# iOS 13 NFC foreground Tag Reading in my App, getting iOS background read as well

Tags: nfc, ios13

I have an app that reads NFC tags in the foreground, user selects NFC option in app and 'Ready to scan' popup appears.. all working well.

With iOS 13 on the latest iPhones and background NFC reading, my app works as expected but I also get the iOS notification alert asking to open the link in Safari.

How can my app foreground read disable the background read of iOS for the current NFC reader session?

The tags may contain generic codes or any of the supported URI's.

Answer (score 0):

There has not been a public API to cancel foreground tag reading up till now.